# How to run R scripts on server from web interface

Tags: r, shiny

There are a few R scripts that several analysts in an organization need to use in their daily life in order to get some analysis and reports.

I was planning to create a Shiny app so that the scripts would be able to run on a server with more memory and processing power, as well as for having some validation of the inputs with selectable or dropdown fields, as now the inputs are typed manually and this creates a lot of errors.

But there are a few problems with this approach (as far as I know):
1) Shiny disconnects when users closes browser or connection, what would finish the execution of the scripts (they can take several hours to run)
2) Once a script is launched it blocks the whole Shiny for doing other tasks (I have unsuccessfully tried to set up parallel computing... we have Windows servers).

Are there any solutions for the issues above to keep on using Shiny?
Maybe Shiny is not the best system for this? Are there any alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: check out https://www.opencpu.org/

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you for shiny, but in general there are 2 tools I can recommend for it: [rundeck](https://www.rundeck.com/open-source) and [script-server](https://github.com/bugy/script-server). Both of them can execute any type of scripts and provide web UI for the script with required inputs, script output, logging, etc.

*disclaimer: I'm the owner of the script-server project*